# Xamarin Forms: Tap and Double Tap

Tags: xamarin.forms, f#

I am looking at Xamarin Forms capabilities for handling screen interaction at the highest level possible - ideally 1 set of code for both iOS and Andoid.  I created a new XF app (Multiplatform -> App in F#, no XAML) and I added this to the default template:

```
type App() =
    inherit Application()
let stack = StackLayout(VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center)
let label = Label(XAlign = TextAlignment.Center, Text = "Welcome to F# Xamarin.Forms!")

do
    let tapRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer()
    let handleTapEvent (sender:Object) (args:EventArgs) =
        label.Text <- "Tapped at " + DateTime.Now.ToString() 
        ()

    let tapEventHandler = new EventHandler(handleTapEvent)
    tapRecognizer.Tapped.AddHandler(tapEventHandler)
    label.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapRecognizer)

    let doubleTapRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer()
    doubleTapRecognizer.NumberOfTapsRequired <- 2
    let handleDoubleTapEvent (sender:Object) (args:EventArgs) =
        label.Text <- "Double Tapped at " + DateTime.Now.ToString() 
        ()

    let doubleTapEventHandler = new EventHandler(handleDoubleTapEvent)
    doubleTapRecognizer.Tapped.AddHandler(doubleTapEventHandler)
    label.GestureRecognizers.Add(doubleTapRecognizer)

    stack.Children.Add(label)
    base.MainPage <- ContentPage(Content = stack)
```

The problem is that the tap still happens as part of the double tap.  Is there a way to recognize a tap or a double tap (versus tap and double tap)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's a know issue. You can use timer to handle such a situation. Wondering If you can avoid double tap with Long press gesture ! 
If you wish to use timers please go through this thread https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20173/tapgesturerecognizer-using-numberoftapsrequired-for-double-tap